# does the react-scripts package get bundled with the built react app?

Tags: reactjs, security, build, react-scripts

I have a react app and I used [snyk](https://snyk.io/) to check its security vulnerabilities, react-scripts introduced three vulnerabilities !, as I know react-scripts is used in the development process but it's included in the dependencies filed not the devDependencies !

regarding that does react-scripts shipped with the built application ? if so, does the application needs it in the production version , because that might make its vulnerabilities alive !